# how to merge month day year columns in date column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

The date is in separate columns

```
Month   Day Year
8   12  1993
8   12  1993
8   12  1993
```

I want to merge it in one column

```
Date
8/12/1993
8/12/1993
8/12/1993
```

I tried

```
df_date = df.Timestamp((df_filtered.Year*10000+df_filtered.Month*100+df_filtered.Day).apply(str),format='%Y%m%d')
```

I get this error

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Timestamp'
```

Comment: I added the code and the error

Comment: Do you want your new `Date` column as `datetime` format or string?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Month': [8, 8, 8], 'Day': [12, 12, 12], 'Year': [1993, 1993, 1993]})

# This way dates will be a DataFrame
dates = df.apply(lambda row: 
    pd.Series(pd.Timestamp(row[2], row[0], row[1]), index=['Date']),
    axis=1)

# And this way dates will be a Series:
# dates = df.apply(lambda row: 
#     pd.Timestamp(row[2], row[0], row[1]),
#     axis=1)
```

`apply` method generates a new `Series` or `DataFrame` iteratively applying provided function (`lambda` in this case) and joining the results.
You can read about `apply` method in [official documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).
And [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) is the explanation of `lambda` expressions.

**EDIT:**
@JohnClements suggested a better solution, using `pd.to_datetime` method:

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(df).to_frame('Date')
```

Also, if you want your output to be a string, you can use

```
dates = df.apply(lambda row: f"{row[2]}/{row[0]}/{row[1]}",
    axis=1)
```

Comment: Or, if the entirety of the DF is just that, then just `pd.to_datetime(df)` will work just fine as it'll use the column names as the required arguments... If there's additional columns not related/named as per date arguments, then subsetting will work fine, eg: `pd.to_datetime(df[['Year', 'Month', 'Day']])`

Comment: What do you mean by ( row[2], row[0], row[1])?

Comment: @JonClements, thank you, haven't known about `pd.to_datetime', this way is much more convenient, I'll add it to the answer

Comment: @Hofsiedge you're well... also... Series objects can be conveniently made into Dataframes... so instead of using the `pd.DataFrame(...)` method, you can also just do: `pd.to_datetime(df).to_frame('Date')`...

Comment: @SihamMB, `apply` interpretes each row as a `Series` object if `axis` argument is set to 1. So the `row[0]` is "Month", `row[1]` is "Day" and `row[2]` is "Year"

Comment: I tried date = pd.to_datetime(df[['Year', 'Month', 'Day']]) and date = pd.to_datetime(df[['Year', 'Month', 'Day']]).to_frame('Date') I get this error OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

Comment: @SihamMB, probably, you have too big "Year" values in some rows to convert them into `pd.Timestamp`. I don't know, what are exact values you have, but you could try `pd.to_datetime(df, errors='ignore')` to ignore errors or `pd.to_datetime(df, errors='coerce')` to omit the incorrect rows and place `NaT`  for them

Comment: @SihamMB, I've added alternative solution for the case if you want your output type to be in string format

Answer (score 0):

#### Using `pd.to_datetime` with `astype(str)`

**1.** as string type:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Month'].astype(str) + df['Day'].astype(str) + df['Year'].astype(str), format='%d%m%Y').dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

   Month  Day  Year        Date
0      8   12  1993  08/12/1993
1      8   12  1993  08/12/1993
2      8   12  1993  08/12/1993
```

**2.** as `datetime` type:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Month'].astype(str) + df['Day'].astype(str) + df['Year'].astype(str), format='%d%m%Y')

   Month  Day  Year       Date
0      8   12  1993 1993-12-08
1      8   12  1993 1993-12-08
2      8   12  1993 1993-12-08
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Month': [8,8,8], 'Day': [12,12,12], 'Year': [1993, 1993, 1993]})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df)
```

Result:

```
   Month  Day  Year       date
0      8   12  1993 1993-08-12
1      8   12  1993 1993-08-12
2      8   12  1993 1993-08-12
```

Info:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 4 columns):
Month    3 non-null int64
Day      3 non-null int64
Year     3 non-null int64
date     3 non-null datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(3)
memory usage: 176.0 bytes
```